# Reference source of this shloka - Niścalātavai bhaktir yā saiva muktiḥ janārdana

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify the reference/source of this shloka,

> Niścalātavai bhaktir yā saiva muktiḥ janārdana

निश्चलात्वै भक्तिर या सैव मुक्तिर जनार्दन

Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently from the [Hari Bhakta Vilasa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/hari-bhakti-vilasa-sanskrit-text/d/doc500840.html), verse 10.93:

> निश्चला त्वयि भक्तिर् या सैव मुक्तिर् जनार्दन ।
> मुक्ता एव हि भक्तास् ते तव विष्णो यतो हरे ॥ ९३ ॥
>
> niścalā tvayi bhaktir yā saiva muktir janārdana |
> muktā eva hi bhaktās te tava viṣṇo yato hare || 93 ||

That said, I've seen people attributing it to the Skanda Purana's Revakhanda. I can see some *similar* lines in that text, but not this exact verse. But it is for sure found in Sanatana Goswami's treatise.